# How to implement Step Progress bar in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to develop a step progress bar in react-native, but so far no success. It must contain 3 dots (filled or not, based on params), a description below it and a line connecting all of them. I've already created the dots and the description, but could'nt connect the dots.

[This is what I'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4QgE.png)

Comment: The dots seem to be connected in the picture you provided. What exactly is your problem? If you have any trouble, provide the code as well, so people are able to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library.
This exactly does, what you are looking for. Thanks

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress-steps